# Proper / canonical setup for Maven on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

In my current project I find myself constantly having to do Alt+F5 (Maven Update) and Maven Install on my Maven dependencies.

Is there a checklist somewhere for how I should setup by pom.xml's to get full Eclipse functionality in dependency resolution?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Maven_ you can enable _Automatically update Maven projects configuration (experimental)_. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not sure what that does, but I'll try it

Comment: It automatically updates your project configurations (including dependencies) on saving the `pom.xml` (without hitting Alt+F5).